# Have experience in/on

Tags: phrase-usage

What's the difference between "have experience in" and "have experience on"?

I have experience in teaching.
I have experience on teaching.

I know the first sentence is right but when can I use the preposition "on"?

Comment: Do you have experience on a yacht?

Comment: Have you seen this question (and others): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138561/experience-in-war-vs-on-war

Answer (score 1):

*In* vs *on* depends on what the experience is about. Experience *in* is used for professions and activities. It is a contraction of "I have experience *in* the practice of medicine." of "I have experience *in* the programming of computers." which becomes "I have experience *in* programming."

The other is used for equipment such as "I have experience *on* the Vax-11780 computer." or "I have experience *on* the Boeing 737 airplane." Think of it as sitting in the saddle or the cockpit of the equipment vs the theoretical practice of the activity.

Comment: I like this distinction and your rationale. However it would be worth the questioner's while considering using "of" as the universal preposition if they are in doubt. I believe that "experience of programming", "experience of the VAX-11780" "experience of the Boeing 737" or, more specifically "experience of programming the VAX-11780" or "experience of maintaining (or flying) the Boeing 737" are just as good as the sentences using 'in' or 'on'.

Comment: @BoldBen I'm not 100% convinced "I have experience of flying the Boeing 737" is as good as "I have experience in flying the Boeing 737" or even "I have experience flying the Boeing 737." Disregarding the fact that it sounds unnatural, the former sounds like it means "I have *experiences* flying the Boeing 737" or "I have *experienced* flying the Boeing 737" which doesn't really communicate competence in the way the OP might want.

Comment: @GeorgeK. It sounds perfectly natural to me, pehaps we're from different lingustic backgrounds or different demographics. I would be more likely to use 'in' or 'on' as appropriate but still consider that "of" would be more appropriate than "in" or "of" used in thr wrong way so would be a good alternative for the OP to use.